# combine multiple gzip compressed files in a tar file

Tags: bash, shell, unix, gzip, cat

I have a really large tar file containing many gzip files. I would like to combine all the gzip files into one gzip file and place in another directory. To view the contents of the tar file I use:

```
tar -zxvf Big.tar
```

which gives:

```
Big/FileA.gz
Big/FileB.gz
Big/FileC.gz
Big/FileD.gz
```

To normally combine multiple gzip files I would move to that directory and use:

```
cat FileA.gz FileB.gz FileC.gz FileD.gz > BigFile.gz
```

However the BigFile.gz would remain in that directory. I'm just not sure how to do this within a tar file and how to have the combined file be written to another directory.

Comment: Where the output file goes is entirely up to what you put on the right-hand side of the `>`. Use a bare filename and it uses the current directory. Use a full or relative path and it will go there instead. I didn't understand the rest of the question about the tar file though. Are you asking how to take the files that are in the tarball and make one bit concat-ed gzip file out of them?

Comment: @EtanReisner For some reason when I used the full path after the ">" it still puts the file in the same directory as the files are originally located. I guess that isn't the most important part of my question though since I can always move it later. Basically I want to know how to concat the files in the tarball (and optimally the concat-ed gzip file would be written outside the tarball)

Comment: That isn't possible. If you put a full(er) path after `>` it will use that full(er) path. It can't use anything else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU tar, you can do:

```
tar -Oxf Big.tar --wildcards 'Big/*.gz' > /tmp/your_file.gz
```

With OS X tar, you have to list the files individually:

```
tar -Oxf Big.tar Big/FileA.gz Big/FileB.gz > /tmp/your_file.gz
```

The salient feature in both is `-O`, which writes the files to stdout.

Here's an example transcript on a GNU system:

```
$ pwd
/home/me

$ tar tf Big.tar
Big/
Big/foo.txt.gz
Big/bar.txt.gz

$ tar -Oxf Big.tar --wildcards 'Big/*.gz' > /tmp/your_file.gz

$ zcat /tmp/your_file.gz
This is the contents of foo.txt
This is the contents of bar.txt
```

Comment: I'm getting an error saying: "tar: Option --wildcards is not supported"

Comment: @user2165857 I'll guess you mean "I don't have GNU tar. I'm using the OS X version", and updated accordingly

Comment: Is `--wildcards` necessary here? Isn't that for `--excludes`? Isn't a glob valid for file selection on its own?

Comment: @EtanReisner It was necessary on my system

Comment: That's interesting. I don't think it should be (it isn't on the CentOS 5 machines I do most of my work). I wonder if that changed. What version of tar are you using? What does `tar --show-defaults` say?

Comment: @EtanReisner tar (GNU tar) 1.27.1, `--format=gnu -f- -b20 --quoting-style=escape --rmt-command=/usr/lib/tar/rmt --rsh-command=/usr/bin/rsh`

Answer (score 0):

Using tar and assuming folder Big has FileA.gz, FileB.gz, etc.:

```
tar -czv -f /path/to/final/BigFile.gz -C Big .
```

Comment: The question here is how to create a single gzip file from a tarball's contents not how to create a tarball from a set of gzip files.

Comment: ok - I just upvoted that other guy's answer.  I like the use of -O and -x